# Get List of Accociated ChangeSets in a Build

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm Working on TFS Custom Build Template, I need to get the list of changesets which are associated to that particular build but not able to achieve the same, I have added the activity of AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems but its asking the current build and last build label, I just need the changesets related to build which got completed.

So can I write a powershell script which will get me the list of changesets which are associated in the build or is there any TFS Activity available in the Workflow by which I can achieve that !

Rgds,
nmistry